# Adding color to subject when emailing with python email module

Tags: python, html, email, smtp, mime

Need to add color for subject when sending email

here is the code, and i want subjects to be in color

```
content = " <html>\
                <body ><p>Hi, </p><p style='font-family:verdana;color:MediumSeaGreen;'>QA </p></body></html>"

msg = MIMEText(content, 'html')
msg['Subject'] = "subject"
to_ = [list@emil.com]
from_ = '{}@test.com'.format(getpass.getuser())

smtp_ = smtplib.SMTP("mail.test.com")
smtp_.set_debuglevel(3)
smtp_.sendmail(from_, to_, msg.as_string())
```

Comment: Subject lines in an email are plain ascii. You can't specify a colour.

Comment: @BoarGules That is not true. Subjects can contain encoded text with (for example) Unicode. There could be implementations in clients allowing colored emoticons or similar. But there is no direct way of setting the color.

Comment: @KlausD. It *is* true. RFC 6532 provides the means to encode Unicode in 7-bit ascii. After encoding, the header is ascii. Unicode does contain coloured emojis (with no guarantees about how the colour will be rendered) but that is not what the OP wanted. There is no comparable standard for encoding colour information in a header, and because the header has to be ascii, there no legal way to insert (say) VT100 escape codes into the header.